# How to create a keyboard shortcut to enter a Unicode shruggie?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I want to create a keyboard shortcut that, when pressed, writes [¯\_(ツ)_/¯](https://emojipedia.org/shrug/)

I use Linux Mint Cinnamon.

Comment: Well now this sucks XD

Comment: You may use compose key. For example https://yakim.org.ua/en/workstations/147-compose-en.html {from deleted answer, but may still be of use}.

Comment: I think I had mistaken this question for what we have seen in Fedora (2016): [Typing Emoji with Fedora 25 Workstation](https://fedoramagazine.org/using-favorite-emoji-fedora-25/), which may support more than just emoji in recent years.

Comment: Grace period note: Waiting for at least one more user to vote any of the answers below. With enough votes, I will leave it to the system to decide automatically. P.S.: I won't be voting myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the keyboard shortcuts menu. I don't have linux mint available, but according to [this blog post](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-the-linux-mint-cinnamon-keyboard-shortcuts-4064754) it's a matter of going to Menu → Keyboard → Shortcuts:
[image: The keyboard menu]
Find 'Custom Shortcuts' in the left bar, and add one with the command `xdotool type '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'`. In 'Keyboard Bindings', bind it to a key (combination) of your choice.

Of course, there are many commands to produce a shrug output; in most cases (given you are running an X server) this'll work fine.

Comment: this does not seem to work for me in pop OS 21.04, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) utility, with a personal configuration file `~/.xbindkeysrc` as:

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'"
  control + shift + 3 # Key code, can change depending on your keyboard
```

To identify the key code you want to use you can do: `xbindkeys -k` and enter keys.